# Is the a standard way to handle intense logging for multiple processes

Tags: c#, multiprocessing, disk-io

> My question is general in nature (no code supplied) BUT I put it on
>   this forum because I believe I could be supplied with definite answers.

I have a windows 8 machine, with 32 cores.

I have one master "App" and 50 independent client "apps" that all communicate via socket IPC.

Each App needs to keep a log of it's activities which results in 3/4 lines of text per second from each app. They are all writing to the same disk drive, but to different files.

I am concerned (though do not actually know) that there may significant hold-ups due to the Apps each waiting for the chance to write to disk.

Can anyone suggest if this is likely to be a bottle neck? Is there a standard way to do deal with this sort of issue?

Comment: Use a dedicated disk if possible.  Try to buffer as much data as possible in RAM and drop data every few seconds if loosing some data is not critical. Avoid SSD for intense read/write operations.

Comment: @Seb do you mean a dedicated disk just for logging? i.e. that all 50 processes write to?

Comment: Distributed Logging through Enterprise Library and MSMQ Distributor Service could be something you'd like to explore. See here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239878/Distributed-Logging-thru-Enterprise-Library-EntL

Comment: Yes, if it is possible, so OS wont interfer in logging operation.  But I think some buffering and a good scheduler could do the job otherwise

Comment: @Seb 2 things. Why not SSD - I actually thought of moving to one! What do you mean by scheduler?

Comment: SSD are good at random reading.  But, intense block overwriting will reduce their lifetime.  And, by scheduler i'm not specific. I mean some scheduling logic ensuring the write will not fall at the same time.

Comment: [Event Tracing for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363668(v=vs.85).aspx) which also is available in .NET is supposed to be the most efficient logging mechanism in Windows and you might want to explore the options available to you. Obviously, if you want to log directly to disk and the disk is too slow ETW will not solve that problem.

Comment: Create a global service that receives log from all tasks and write them to physical memory.

Comment: Someone has mentioned log4net, and that I set up each app to "Write" to a central "controller"(I don't know what the proper terminology for this is). Is that a good approach? Does anyone have an idea how that might compare to ETW?